# Can Dialyzer see through Mnesia transaction functions?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, dialyzer

Here is some code with an error which I think Dialyzer should be able to spot:

```
-module(myapp_thing).

-spec exists(pos_integer()) -> yes | no.
exists(Id) ->
    myapp_mnesia:thing_exists(Id).
```

```
-module(myapp_mnesia).

thing_exists(Id) ->
    Exists = fun() -> 
                     case mnesia:read({thing, Id}) of
                         [] -> false;
                         _ ->  true
                     end
             end,
    mnesia:activity(transaction, Exists).
```

`myapp_thing:exists/1` is specified as returning `yes | no`, but the return type will actually be `true | false` (i.e., `boolean()`), which is what is returned from `myapp_mnesia:thing_exists/1`.

However, running Dialyzer on myapp passes it without warnings.

If I change `myapp_mnesia:thing_exists/1` to just return `true` I get an appropriate warning; similarly if I add the right spec:

```
-spec session_exists(pos_integer()) -> boolean().
```

But it looks like Dialyzer can't look inside the mnesia transaction function Exists, or for some other reason can't infer a return type for thing_exists.

So, are mnesia transaction functions a barrier for Dialyzer, or is there a more general barrier to Dialyzer's return type inference?

Comment: As far as I can see, `mnesia:activity/2` doesn't have a type `-spec`.  Adding something like `-spec mnesia:activity(atom(), fun(()->X)) -> X.` might help (though I haven't tried it).

Comment: You can have type variables in function specs!?  Cool!  http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#id76207  However, I'd rather not fiddle with the mnesia source.  I am typing the functions in myapp_mnesia.  I'd like to know more about barriers to Dialyzer's reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mnesia_tm:execute_transaction`, the provided fun is being called inside a `catch`, which means that the return type collapses into `term()` as far as Dialyzer is concerned.  Thus Dialyzer is unable to conclude that the return type of `mnesia:activity/2` is the same as that of the provided function, and thus needs an explicit type spec to that effect.

Besides, I believe that Dialyzer generally never infers a return value type based on the return value of a function provided as an argument.  For example, with this module:

```
-module(foo).

-export([foo/1]).

foo(F) ->
    F(42).
```

typer shows the following:

```
$ typer /tmp/foo.erl

%% File: "/tmp/foo.erl"
%% --------------------
-spec foo(fun((_) -> any())) -> any().
```

though if I add the explicit type spec `-spec foo(fun((_) -> X)) -> X.`, then typer accepts it.

(I'm sure the Dialyzer developers will have a more complete and insightful answer to this.)